# node.js - How to identify user in Google Login

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-api

I set up a Google login for my application and am trying to get a unique identifier for the user, so when the user enters a reading I can enter it into the database as that particular user's entry. How can I do this?

Below is some of the login code, I've set up so far. Pretty new to node.js and so the following code will probably be rather sloppy and hacked together. The tutorial I happened to follow split app.js with a file in routes called index.js.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest1');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Make db accessible to the router
app.use(function(req,res,next){
        req.db = db;
        next();
});
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

**routes/index.js**

```
 passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

var processRequest = function(token, refreshToken, profile, callback){
   process.nextTick(function(){
           console.log('id : '+ profile.id);
           console.log('name :'+ profile.displayName);
           console.log('email :' + profile.emails);
           console.log('token : '+ token);
   });
};

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://ec2-#########.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/Glucometer"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
      return done(null, profile);
    });
  }
));


router.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
                                            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'] }),
  function(req, res){
    // The request will be redirected to Google for authentication, so this
    // function will not be called.
  });

router.get('/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/Glucometer');
  });
```

**glucometer.jade** - The view users are directed to when they log in. Currently, for storing items in the DB I am just having the user type in their username manually. But obviously this is unreliable and I should just have the user type in a reading and the app will handle the timestamp/username entries.

```
extends layout

block content
        h1.
                Glucometer Application
        table
                thead
                        tr
                                th Username
                                th Timestamp
                                th Blood Sugar
                tbody
                        each reading, i in glucometer
                                tr
                                        td #{reading.username}
                                        td #{reading.Timestamp}
                                        td #{reading.Bloodsugar}

        h1.
                Add An Entry
        form#formAddEntry(name="glucometer",method="post",action="/glucometer")
                input#inputUserName(type="text", placeholder="Username", name="username")
                input#inputTimestamp(type="text", placeholder="Timestamp", name="Timestamp")
                input#inputBloodsugar(type="text", placeholder="Blood Sugar", name="Bloodsugar")
                button#btnSubmit(type="submit") submit

        a(href='/logout') Logout
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem you're trying to solve? You're trying to generate a unique user ID but at the same time the user also enters a username??

Comment: The user entering the username is just temporary. It was to test and make sure I can add stuff into the DB. Now I want to get rid of that and automatically generate a unique user ID based off the Google login.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use  mongo's _id as the user id?

Comment: I need to be able to associate each Google account with its data. So I was thinking I could use some unique user identifier from Google as the UID and then query and only return results for that UID. e.g. If A@google.com logs in, then I'll only pull up data for A@google.com and If B logs in then I'll only pull up data for B@google.com, etc.

Comment: So I found a way of figuring this out. Apparently, the user info is available on my auth/google/callback URL, but nowhere else. So if I set a global variable at the top and then set it to req.user in the callback, then I can access the user info throughout my route file. This doesn't seem right though because shouldn't I be able to access the user info on any page since the session is logged in?